# How to insert a value in Database when using MVC identity framework in AspNetUsers Table?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I want to insert a value in DB and I am using the Asp.Net Identity framework, in my Register method when a new user registers I also want to add a new Id which is client_id by default this id is not inserted by the identity framework?

```
if (User.IsInRole("Avanceon")) 
{
    var MaxCustomerId = db.AspNetUsers.Max(x => x.Customer_Id);
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {   
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.UserName, Email = model.Email };
        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            // Assign Role to user Here 
            await this.UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, model.RoleName);

            // Ends Here
            // await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
            ViewBag.userCreated = user.UserName + " Created Successfully";
            ViewBag.Name = new SelectList(context.Roles.ToList(), "Name", "Name");
            MaxCustomerId = MaxCustomerId + 1;
            // db.AspNetUsers.LastOrDefault().Customer_Id = MaxCustomerId;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return View();
            //return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        AddErrors(result);
    }
}

ViewBag.Name = new SelectList(context.Roles.ToList(), "Name", "Name");
return View(model);
```

Comment: There was a good series on Channel9 around customising ASP.NET Identity authentication. I think this episode is what you're after. IT is very similar to the below answer but includes the changes required on the Entity Framework end. https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Customizing-ASPNET-Authentication-with-Identity/02#time=18m15s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You normally can't simply insert any data to `AspNetUsers` table. You'll need create a class and inherit it from `IdentityUser` and do the necessary changes in your class.

With code first you should create a class say `ApplicationUser` which inherits `IdentityUser`. And add the property there:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    public string ClientID { get; set; }
}
```

And then target `ApplicationUser` (instead of `IdentityUser`) in your code:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser
{
    UserName = model.UserName,
    Email = model.Email,
    ClientID = model.ClientID,
};
```

Make below changes as well:

In `ConfigureServices` method of `Startup.cs`

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>();
```

In AccountController,

```
private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
```

Add migration for this change to take effect

Comment: Hi i tried your solution but still not inserting the value???\

Comment: You will need to create migration for this as well. Then it should work

Comment: If the user already exists and you just want to update the Client ID, what do you use instead of var user = new ApplicationUser { }; ?